# Google sheets grabbing info depending on other column

Tags: google-sheets

Essentially I'm trying to figure out a formula that checks if Column A has the string "example", then grab the data in the corresponding row for Column B.

So if A1 says "Example" grab B1 data but I need to do this for multiple rows at the same time if possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far? *"New to this website, sorry if this isn't how you ask questions"* Please read [the help](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) to find more info.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 12 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
Column A   | Column B | Column C
My example | 100      | =IF(ISERROR(FIND("example",A1)),"",B1)
```

[`FIND` function is case-sensitive.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126)
If you want a case-insensitive search you should [use `SEARCH` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154).

If your string can vary, you can place it in cell `D1`, for instance and reference to it:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND($D$1,A1)),"",B1)
```

If the string is variable per row, add a third column

```
Column A   | Column B | Column C | Column D
My example | 100      | example  | =IF(ISERROR(FIND(C1,A1)),"",B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **C1** enter:

```
=filter(A1:B6,A1:A6="example")
```

[image]

make the "6" whatever you need.